# How to slow down requests to an arbitrary service in container (for testing)

Tags: docker, testing, trafficshaping

I need to test how my application handles timeouts. So, I need a very slow response from the server. How can I do this in the most general way, regardless of the specific application in the container? In other words, I need to emulate a very, very busy container or a very, very slow network. One more condition: I can't change the application code in the container, but I can change the Dockerfile and rebuild the image.